# Android Tab spacing/padding options

Tags: android

Using the example http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html I've made  a slight change by adding a HorizontalScrollView to the layout and then duplicating the instances of the tabs. Is there a way to better space out or add padding so that the tabs do not bunch up?

Change made to main.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fillViewport="true"
                      android:scrollbars="none">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

In the public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity i've added

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));       
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: OP solved the problem by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) 
    { 
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(40,0,40,0); 
    }
```

By the way tab is deprecated in newer versions. You may consider learning [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Comment: Thank I'll take a look at Fragments but I did also find that this will work.  for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(40,0,40,0); 
        }

Comment: Good to know. Learned something. I am editing my answer with your comment.